# What is the best way to add a background in Unity - preformance

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, skybox

I have a 3D app, my camera doesn't move- despite "clipping planes- Far"
That's why I can choose between 3 options-

1. Skybox (and use only 1 side of it). Not my favorite option because blurry and cropped.
2. Canvas+ Image (the problem is that I need to keep playing with its size because of the Camera's far option).
3. 3D quad with an image material (the same problem as in 2).

Which option will give me the performance on mobile?

Comment: When Canvas' `Render Mode` is set to `Screen Space - Camera`, it's positioned according to the Far plane position. If you set the `Plane Distance` to 1, you shouldn't have to adjust the size. Have you tried this setup?

Comment: true. but then the canvas hides my 3D game objects and I just need the canvas to be a background...